# Displaying different texts to different users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a Google Sheet that will display a hyperlink to users, but this hyperlink is unique to each user. I managed to make it work, but then realize that when multiple users log in at the same time, there will be a problem (last user's links will be displayed). How can I resolve this?

I have already managed to create a sheet that will display a link that is customized for each user using vlookup to a table with first column user emails, and second column the unique url. I then use the onOpen() function to include a line of code that will set the value of a cell to the user's email, and it is this cell that the vlookup refer to.

Basically, on Sheet1 I have a cell with the formula:
=hyperlink(link1,text1)
link1 and text1 are named ranges referring to two cells in another Sheet2 that are customized using a vlookup to a table, and referring to a cell which contains the current user's email (obtained through onOpen() function).

I hope that each user can see a link customized to them and which they can click on and be led to their own customized page. However, when multiple users log in around the same time, the cell which the vlookup functions refer to is quickly overwritten by the latest user who opened the sheet. Is there a way to do this so that everyone really sees a customized link and the link persists for each user? I am game to consider options beyond Google Sheet.

Comment: It is not possible to show different cell content for multiple users at the same time. Use alternatives. For example, you can show UI elements: dialog boxes, sidebars and so on with personal hyperlinks, because all of them are client-side. On the contrary, generic cells are server side objects, they are common for all users and display the same content.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: As Ruben said use a dialog or a sidebar and you can store user information in PropertiesService ... there's three different options user, document or script ... take your pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... then realize that when multiple users log in at the same time, there will be a problem (last user's links will be displayed). How can I resolve this?

As it was already mentioned on a comment, it's not possible to show a different cell content to users that are accessing the same spreadsheet at the same time because the real-time feature of the G Suite Document Editors.

Among other alternatives, you could use Google Apps Script to create a menu to open a dialog/sidebar to show the personalized hyperlink or to automatically open the linked page.